# Unable to access MySql root user, even after setting the password through safemode in linux terminal

Tags: mysql, linux

1) service stoped

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

2) started in safe mode

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

3) user created

```
mysql -u root
```

4) setting passwd

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';
```

exit from the mysql console,
and restart the service and trying to access mysql console with

```
mysql -u root -p my_password     

[vikram@VoltyLinux ~]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *******
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

Comment: for kicks, try it with no space between dash p and the password

Comment: maybe you should check the hostname field of the record(s) in the user table

Comment: as @DanielAlder says, get back in with step2, and issue `select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='root';` and see if you have multiple rows of output where the hashed password is different with an eyeball check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in as before in Step 2, that is, restart mysql daemon in safe-mode.

Issue the command

```
select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='root';
```

cut and paste output into a text editor for comparison (of the hashed password column values) before and after the following.

For each row notice the `host` column. In the following example I am assuming I have two rows. One row has `%` as host, the next has `localhost`

For each row that had a `host` variation, you will issue one command. So in my example above, I would be issuing 2 commands in total, such as:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('MyNewPassword');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPassword');
```

run

```
select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='root';
```

cut and paste that into text editor. Notice the change to the password hashes.

Shutdown the daemon from safe mode, and restart normally.

Try to login as root with MyNewPassword

Here are a few links. The one for [SET PASSWORD Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html), and an often next step for [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

For the narrow scope of this question, that is to login, the grants would not be necessary. But without proper grants to databases, one would be sandboxed, not able to do much, other than simple commands like `select now();`

I am not suggesting that your root user does not have privileges once the password is changed. The Grants are necessary for normal users to be sure.