# Can't connect as MySQL user created with Ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I created a MySQL user via Ansible:

```
- name: MySQL user has ALL THE PRIVILEGES (in order to connect remotely)
  mysql_user: name="{{ database_user }}" password="{{ database_password }}" priv="*.*:ALL,GRANT" host="%" state=present
  notify: restart MySQL

- name: restart MySQL
  service: name=mysql state=restarted
```

The user is created, and I am able to connect from `localhost`, but not from any other machines.

Interestingly, running:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '{{ username }}'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

as the `root` MySQL user then allows those connections from any other machine.

I've reproduced this on a couple of Ubuntu 14.04 hosts with Ansible 1.9.4 installed via `brew` running on Mac OS 10.11.

How do I correctly specify `mysql_user` to enable connections from any host?

Comment: on your first block of code, make database_user=broomhilda, and run that block. Then run `select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='broomhilda'` ... and make note of that info somewhere like in Notepad. Then run your "interestingly" block, and do the same. As you know, host='%' is anyhost, perhaps look at what I wrote up [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33478741) today

Comment: because what you did in the "interestingly" block was to create a superuser, as seen [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5016587)

Comment: so what you may have done in your first block is to create a user with host<> '%' that has access on localhost, then a 2nd user with the next chunk. Because the 2nd chunk, even though it is a Grant stmt, also creates users !

Answer (score 0):

You can check what's being created on the host by looking into `mysql.user` table - there might be something wrong with the user name, password or host.

And it's not necessary to restart MySQL daemon after adding users.